# Find $f(\dfrac{\pi}{2})$. Provided two functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose

> $f(x)=\int_0^{g(x)}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}~dt$ and $g(x)=\int_0^{\cos x}1+\sin t^2~dt$ Find $f(\dfrac{\pi}{2})$

I evaluated everything and ended up with

> $f(\dfrac{\pi}{2})=\dfrac {2}{1+\int_0^{\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}} 1+\sin t^2~dt}$

As usual I am stuck at evaluating the indefinite integral in the denominator. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0$, 
 $$g(\frac{\pi}{2})=\int_0^{\cos\frac{\pi}{2}}1+\sin t^2~dt
=\int_0^{0}1+\sin t^2~dt=0,$$
which implies
$$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\int_0^{g(\frac{\pi}{2})}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}~dt
=\int_0^{0}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}~dt=0.$$